# Can I add X-Message-Delivery to php mailer?

Tags: email, phpmailer

I opened source code of my email found an attribute called : X-Message-Delivery.  What does it mean?  Is it important? 
Can I add this attribute to my php mailer, is it modifiable?

Answer (score 1):

You can add any headers you like with PHPMailer. Whether they do or mean anything is an entirely separate matter. Anything starting with `X-` is used to denote a non-standard, and usually informational, header (defined in RFC822).

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614312/x-message-delivery-in-hotmail-messages) to see what that particular header means - it's informational and added by hotmail.